# Add a selection listener to package explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, package-explorer

I'm currently developing a plugin for eclipse. The thing is that, I want when the user click a specific type of project, folder or file, insert in the properties view some attributes to edit. I found some examples, but I still don't know how to add a listener to the package explorer from the begining. Does Any one know the solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When the Package View is active it controls the Properties View and it would be very difficult to alter what is shown. Or do you mean the Properties dialog?

Comment: I mean the properties view. I really don't know how to make an extension from that view. Any hints??